# `setState` in React portal containing a text input causes browser to scroll in Safari

Tags: reactjs, input, text, safari, portal

If you place a text input inside a React portal overlay and the content adjacent to it scrolls, any event that changes state causes Safari to scroll to the portal (which is the bottom of the page).

**To recreate**

- Portal must be appended as a sibling element to the root (and a child to the body)
- A text input must be placed inside the portal
- `setState` must be called
- `setState` doesn't have to affect the value of the text input
- Content in root must be long enough to scroll the page
- Only happens in Safari (currently using 11.1.2)

  import * as React from 'react';
  import {createPortal} from 'react-dom';

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    const {portalActive, randomBoolean} = this.state;

  togglePortal = () => {
      this.setState(({portalActive}) => {
        return {portalActive: !portalActive};
      });
    };

  toggleBoolean = () => {
      this.setState(({randomBoolean}) => {
        return {randomBoolean: !randomBoolean};
      });
    };

  render() {
      const textInput = ;
      const portal = this.state.portalActive
        ? ({textInput})
        : null;

  ```
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={this.togglePortal}
      {portal}
      {Array.from({length: 40}).map(() => (
        <p>Content that causes scrolling</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
  ```

  }
  }

  class Portal extends React.Component {
    const {children, idPrefix} = this.props;
    componentWillMount() {
      const portalNode = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(portalNode);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      document.body.removeChild(portalNode);
    }
    render() {
      return createPortal(children, portalNode);
    }
  }

[image]

[image]

Comment: window.scrollTo(0, 0); this does not necessarily fix your problem but might be a work around until you find a solution. This scrolls to the top of the page

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo. Yes, I was trying to avoid a hacky solution, but it might be my only choice.